# Slurm: select nodes with specified number of CPUs

Tags: slurm

I'm using slurm on a cluster where single partitions have dissimilar nodes. Specifically, the nodes have varying # CPUs.  My code is a single-core application being used for a parameter sweep and thus I want to fully use an (eg.) 32 CPU node by sending it 32 jobs.

**How can I select nodes (within a named partition) that have a specified number of CPUs?**

I know my Partition configuration via

```
 sinfo -e -p <partition_name> -o "%9P %3c %.5D %6t " -t idle,mix

PARTITION          CPU   NODES  STATE  
<partition_name>    16     63    mix    
<partition_name>    32     164   mix
```

But if I use a submissions script like

```
[snip preamble]

#SBATCH --partition <partition_name> # resource to be used
#SBATCH --nodes 1 # Num nodes
#SBATCH -N 1 # Num cores per job
#SBATCH --cores-per-socket=32 # Cores per node
```

the slurm scheduler says

```
sbatch: error: Socket, core and/or thread specification can not be satisfied
```

PS. A minor correction: my code to get partition info isn't the best.  Just in case anyone looks up this question later, here is a better query (using X,Y for socket, core counts) that helps identify the problem that damien's excellent answer solved

```
sinfo -e -p <partition_name> -o "%9P %3c %.3D %6t %2X %2Y %N" -t idle,mix
```

Comment: Alternative question: What happens if a 32-job script a'la
   `for RUN_ID in seq RUN_ID_FIRST RUN_ID_LAST; do
    matlab -nojvm -singleCompThread -r "try myscript(RUN_ID); catch me; disp(' *** error'); end; exit"  > ./result_RUN_ID &
done`  gets sent to a 16 core node?

Comment: What  <partition_name> are you using? Because it shouldn't work if you chose the 16-CPU partition.

Comment: There is a single <partition_name> and that partition contains a bunch of different nodes with different CPUs.  Therefore I can't select the 32 CPU node by the partition name and am looking to submit a resource request that ensures I am matched to an appropriate node within the partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To strictly answer your question: With

```
#SBATCH --cores-per-socket=32
```

you request 32 core per socket, which is per physical CPU. I guess those machines have two CPUs so you should request something like

```
#SBATCH --sockets-per-node=2
#SBATCH --cores-per-socket=16
```

Another way of requesting the same is to ask for

```
#SBATCH --nodes 1
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node 32
```

But please note that, if your cluster allows node sharing, what you do seems more suited for job arrays :

```
#SBATCH --ntasks 1
#SBATCH --arrays 1-32
IDS=($(seq RUN_ID_FIRST RUN_ID_LAST))
RUN_ID=${IDS[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
matlab -nojvm -singleCompThread -r "try myscript(${RUN_ID}); catch me; disp(' *** error'); end; exit" > ./result_${RUN_ID}
```

This will launch 32 independent jobs, each taking care of running the Matlab script for one value of the parameter sweep.

To answer your additional question; if a 32-process job is scheduled on a 16-CPU node, the node will be overloaded, and depending on the containment solution set up by the administrators, your processes might impact others' jobs and slow them down.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  To check my understanding: the job array solution is entirely dependent on the cluster config right?  If the cluster DIDN'T support node sharing then I'd be occupying 32 nodes and only using a single CPU on each node?

Comment: Correct. With an array you submit 32 independent 1-CPU jobs. If Slurm is not allowed to pack them on the nodes, then you end up with a lot of wasted resource. But if Slurm is allowed to pack them, then you help a lot minimising idle resource.

Comment: Hm.  Is there a way to know if a partition supports packing via terminal commands?

Comment: `scontrol show config | grep -e "SelectType\b"` must return `select/cons_res` and `scontrol show partition | grep -o "Shared=[^ ]*"`  must not be `EXCLUSIVE`